# Using both OpenCV 2.4.9 and OpenCV 3.0 in the same Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, machine-learning, computer-vision

Since the documentation of OpenCV 3.0 machine learning library is obsolete (there is also a bug in svm->load), I'd like to use OpenCV 2.4.9 machine learning library instead. However, my entire program in which I want to use machine learning algorithms is written based on OpenCV 3.0 and it is a long code.

Because of conflicts, I can't link to two different OpenCV libraries in the same project. One idea is to define another project in the same solution in which I can link to OpenCV 2.4.9 but I don't know how to do this properly (apparently, this second project can't be a static library because it's difficult to link a static library to another library). I should be able to pass values between the two projects (i.e. between my original program using OpenCV 3.0 and machine learning algorithms using OpenCV 2.4.9).

Comment: Create a DLL project for OpenCV 2.4.9. It should contain code which uses OpenCV 2.4.9. Link your OpenCV 3.0 project with the dll generated by the other project.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. You can upgrade to OpenCV 3.1 where most of the OpenCV 3.0 bugs are now fixed